# Can't assign value to field in custom class where field is object

Tags: excel, vba

I have my custom class for VBA. I create field where will keep reference of object Worksheet:

```
Private ws As Worksheet
```

write properties:

```
Property Get TargetWorksheet() As Worksheet
    TargetWorksheet = ws
End Property
Property Set TargetWorksheet(ByRef newws As Worksheet)
    ws = newws
End Property
```

but when I try assign value

```
Dim mylist As CustomPropertWS
mylist.TargetWorksheet = Sheet1
or
Set mylist.TargetWorksheet = Sheet1
```

macro always did throws an exception
 "object variable or with block variable not set". How can I set fields with objects like it?
Thanks.

Comment: Just FYI, property procedures always pass `ByVal` so your `ByRef` is ignored.

Comment: @Rory oh, well thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make the following modifications to your class module:

***CustomPropertWS* Class Code**

```
Private ws As Worksheet

Property Get TargetWorksheet() As Worksheet
    Set TargetWorksheet = ws
End Property

Property Set TargetWorksheet(ByRef newws As Worksheet)
    Set ws = newws
End Property
```

Your Sub, which calls the Class code:

***TestClass* Module Code**

```
Option Explicit

Sub TestClass()

Dim mylist As CustomPropertWS

Set mylist = New CustomPropertWS ' initiate the new class
'Set mylist.TargetWorksheet = Worksheets("Sheet1")
Set mylist.TargetWorksheet = Sheet1 ' <-- this method passes the worksheet's codename

Debug.Print mylist.TargetWorksheet.Name ' just for DEBUG

End Sub
```